# How to change color of entities shown in Google map?

Tags: google-maps

The present colouring scheme of Google maps gives me a challenge to differentiate between the road and its surroundings.  The contrast between these two are simply not sufficient for me and my screen guard is making it worse.

The following is how it looks in my screen (ignoring the volume notification) and the road color is not that apparently different from its surroundings during day time.

[image]
I am looking for some way to customize the colors of the entities, like road, buildings, grounds etc so that it will be vivid in my screen. Few navigation apps usually provide a toggle between day and night mode. I will be even happy with that. It will be great if a theme can be applied to switch colors, if it is not too much at this stage!

Are there any hacks/ways to achieve this? 
I am running  Google Maps (version 6.11.1) in LG P500 (a.k.a Optimus One) on CM10 Android 4.1.

All my search effort only results about changing colors through API, which I do not want.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a high-contrast night mode, but I can't find it now...

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to achieve this in Google Maps. You can send feedback within the app, so you could suggest that they add such a feature.

There are alternative map apps you might like to try instead. Those based on the free OpenStreetMap database usually allow you to change which *tile server* to use, which gets you a completely different visualization of the map data: some tile servers are optimized for particular uses, such as cycling or marine navigation.

Answer (score 0):

With the newly designed Google Maps app, they have improved the appearance regarding contrast between roads and buildings even in day time. I couldn't find any day/night mode in settings, though.

Here is a screenshot for the same map taken in Google Maps version 7.5.0 (#705001723).

[image: same map, newer version]